# Add animation on click function

Tags: javascript

I have search icon width onclick function

```
<span onclick="mobileSearch()" 
      class="flaticon-magnifier-tool search-iconmob hidden-lg hidden-md"> 
</span>
```

and form:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" c .........
```

form by default is hidden and script above works well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mobileSearch() {
    var x = document.getElementById("searchform");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
            x.style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

my problem is that, I can't add animation effect.. how to make this? best will be slide down effect.

Comment: On the right track - just change css class instead of style. You may want to look at https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ which is a collection of easy to use transitions.

Comment: Look at  this css animation.https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation_speed

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: yes I'm using jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this task I would use jQuery, it would be very simple to achieve the effect you're looking for using the fadeToggle() function.

Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").fadeToggle();
        $("#div2").fadeToggle("slow");
        $("#div3").fadeToggle(3000);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Demonstrate fadeToggle() with different speed parameters.</p>

<button>Click to fade in/out boxes</button><br><br>

<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div>
<br>
<div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:green;"></div>
<br>
<div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:blue;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can test it clicking [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadetoggle).

Comment: first click is ok fadein, second click must hide again, how to make this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't to want use jQuery. You can simply create css classes and set for them `transition` property and also  use keyframe. Then on click  toggle  css class. Simple example of css (your  should be more complicate):

```
.class { top: 0, position: absolute, transition: .3s }

.slideDown { top: 99999px }
```